# Is it possible to get an aggregated result per row in Clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to write a query to get an aggregated metric for each row of a result set in Clickhouse. The idea is that for each row with matching a grouping ID I want to select a time window for the 60 seconds following the current row and get a sum of some value column but so far I've been unable to figure out a query to achieve this. Below is an example of what I tried using a join but I'm getting errors. I think this is down to not being able to access subquery columns from the outer query:

```sql
select time, groupID, value, summed.addedValue 
from Events 
where groupID = 1234 as current
any inner join 
select groupID, sum(value) as addedValue 
from Events 
where groupID = 1234 and time < (current.time + 60) and time > current.time
group by groupID as summed
```

I'm wondering is this kind of query possible to achieve? It's essentially a sliding 60 second window to get summed values but I want it to cover every possible 60 second window which is why I want to calculate it for each row. Maybe there's a function in Clickhouse to achieve something like this or is it something I'll have to do in code after we get a result set?

Answer (score 0):

Correlated subqueries are not currently supported in ClickHouse.

Though you might try the following: explode the Events table 60 times using [ARRAY JOIN](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/select/#array-join-clause) and [range](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/array_functions/#rangen) to produce new column with `time - N`, which will mean that this row belongs to bucket for `time` moment and then `GROUP BY` it back using that column.